# Override save() method in model to prepopulate it with current user Django

Tags: django, django-models

So I know what to do in view to prepopulate model with the current user name.
But how (if it is possible at all) do I override save() method in model to prepopulate it with the current user id or current user name? As far as I know there's no way i can get request.user from model variables.

Here's my model. Thank you in advance!

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='url', unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=100, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created at')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='views')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='posts')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='posts')

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: You would do that in your view or form not in the model's `save` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by a middleware

```
from app.models import Post
class GetUserMidlleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
   
     def __call__(self, request):
         Post.thread.request = request         
         response = self.get_response(request)
         return response


class Post(Models.model):
   thread = threading.local()
   def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
      self.user = self.thread.request.user
      super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

In the save function get the user from the thread as shown